# MessageBox Expand Button for further error description

Tags: c#, wpf, error-handling, try-catch, messagebox

Is there a way to have a Messagebox show at first the Error Description, and then if an Expand button is pressed, show a further error description? Maybe to show the exact error which .NET gives.

Comment: No. That's not what MessageBox is designed for. You'll have to create your own window for that purpose. It won't be hard though :)

Comment: This question doesn't have a valid answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is example of   [WPF Common TaskDialog](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22511/WPF-Common-TaskDialog-for-Vista-and-XP)

[image]

Follow above link it might be helpful to you...

Comment: I have chosen the Version with the self made windows form. With the creator of the class i give the error messages to the form

Comment: That CodeProject article has been deleted.